# MessageBox if Recordset Update is Successful

Tags: validation, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, recordset

In Access 2007, I have a form to add a new contact to a table:

```
RecSet.AddNew
RecSet![Code_Personal] = Me.txtCodePersonal.Value
RecSet![FName] = Me.TxtFName.Value
RecSet![LName] = Me.txtLName.Value
RecSet![Tel Natel] = Me.txtNatTel.Value
RecSet![Tel Home] = Me.txtHomeTel.Value
RecSet![Email] = Me.txtEmail.Value
RecSet.Update
```

This has worked so far, and the contact has successfully been aded. But I'm having two problems:

1. I want to display a messagebox to tell the user the contact was successfully added
2. If the contact was not successfully added because

   1. A contact with this name already exists
   2. A different issue
      Then display a message box "Contact already exists" or "error occured" respectively.

My idea of doing this is:

```
If recSet.Update = true Then
MsgBox "Paolo Bernasconi was successfully added"
Else if RecSet![FName] & RecSet![LName] 'already exist in table
MsgBox "Contact already exists"
Else 
MsgBox "An unknown error occured"
```

I know this code is wrong, and obviously doesn't work, but it's just to give you an idea of what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks for all your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an error handler to your procedure.

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
```

Then display the "success" notice to user immediately after updating the recordset.

```
RecSet.Update
MsgBox RecSet![FName] & " " & RecSet![FName] & _
    " was successfully added"
```

If the update attempt fails, flow control passes to the `ErrorHandler` section.

```
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Oops!"
```

Undoubtedly you want something more refined than an "Oops!" message.  A slick approach is to use a `Select Case` block to customize the response based on error number.

Determine whether the contact exists already before attempting to add it.

```
strCriteria = "Fname = '" & RecSet![FName] & "' AND LName = '" & _
    RecSet![LName] & "'"
Debug.Print strCriteria
If DCount("*", "YourTable", strCriteria) > 0 Then
    ' do not attempt to add it again
    MsgBox "Contact already exists"
Else
    RecSet.AddNew
    ' and so forth
End If
```

Check the `Debug.Print` output in case I made a mistake when building `strCriteria`.

The intention here is to avoid the duplication error condition ... by only attempting to add a contact which doesn't exist.  So that error should not happen, and any *other* errors will be dealt with by the error handler.